# How to place my own log file to the right place with the logging package in Python3?

Tags: python, linux, unix, logging

I want to place the log file of my own application to the right place. I am not sure but I think on unixoid-systems it is `/var/log`.
But there are problems with the permissions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging, logging.handlers

_LOG_FILENAME = '/var/log/myapp.log'

log = logging.getLogger('')
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(_LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=10240, backupCount=3)
log.addHandler(fh)

log.info('log message')
```

Result in this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./log.py", line 8, in <module>
    fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(_LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=10240, backupCount=3)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/handlers.py", line 150, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/handlers.py", line 57, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 992, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1016, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/myapp.log'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach taking the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) into account is `$XDG_DATA_HOME`.

For my example it would be `~/.local/share/myapp`.

If the logs are less important also `$XDG_STATE_HOME` (`~/.local/state/myapp`) could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

By default, to place your log file in /var/log, your application must be run as root.

tip : create a sub directory and set good owner

```
 mkdir /var/log/myapp
 chown myuser /var/log/myapp
```

best regard

Comment: It is a user application and won't run as root.